# C++ find code paths that might use uninitialized variables before run-time

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, static-analysis, clang++

I want to detect variables which may be used uninitialized. I've tried `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and even `-Weffc++`. Is there a way (either with the compiler or an external tool) to detect this kind of problem? There's an example below of the kind of potential problem I'd rather detect statically than as a run-time problem.

If no iterations of the `for` loop are run then `prev` will still be uninitialized when the `if` is reached and then a `SEGFAULT` when `prev` is used..

```
decltype(params.begin()) prev;
for (auto it = params.begin();
        std::prev(params.end()) - (it + max_chunk_size - 1) >= 0;
        prev = it += max_chunk_size) {

     auto val = {it, it+max_chunk_size};
}
if (prev != params.end()) {
    auto val = {prev, params.end()};
}
```

Comment: `auto prev = params.end();` would solve the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, `prev = params.begin()` is what I did. I want to find other instances more thoroughly than by proof reading.

Comment: i suggest using valgrind under linux systems to detect such problems

Comment: @chewsocks What I was attempting to demonstrate was if you initialize the variable to begin with, using whatever value works for you, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that can be run on a large code base to detect possibly-uninitialized variables?

Comment: Rust does an unbelievably good job of this sort of thing. Hopefully C++ will catch up in terms of warnings.

Comment: @NathanOliver I could have explained better, I usually do, I meant to catch cases if/when I make a mistake.

Comment: @bartop I though valgrind could only detect that kind of thing after the path has been taken?

Comment: @Xirema Not in the sense that any one program/library is large; but I would like to check everything I write.

Comment: @chewsocks I am not sure what You mean. All in all, valgrind does great job detecting usage of uninitialized data. Except of it, I suggest usage of clang static analyzer https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/. I think it is best free static analyzer, if not THE best one.You can also try to use memory and undefined behaviour sanitizers.

Comment: @bartop I haven't had a change to look at valgrind, but (sadly) clang-analyzer (scan-build), cppcheck, and clang-tidy all missed it.